# Using Netsh on Windows 10

Tags: packet, netsh

I am stuck in a scenario where I can't install third party softwares to capture the network traffic on Windows 2012 R2. Earlier I have used netsh on Windows 2008 R2. The command which I have used to capture traffic on Windows 2008 R2 was:

```
netsh trace start capture=yes IPv4.Address=ip_address
```

But in case of the Windows 2012 R2 the trace command is not present.

Am I missing something? If not, what could be the workaround for this?

Comment: That worked for me on WS2016 with an elevated cmd.

Comment: I tried with the elevated privilege on WS2k12 but no success. I think that is not available in win2k12.

Comment: Confirmed that `netsh trace` is available and working on Windows Server 2012 R2.